# Drawing wide image in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a bit of an issue getting an image (size 1.25MB, resolution 1080 height by 2520 width) to run on my android emulator. I can't figure out why resolution does this, but I'd like to preserve as much details as possible. So far I've tried:

Moving the image to different mipmap folders (no effect, image doesn't even get displayed and if drawable is say 120x480, that will be displayed, mipmaps don't work as source AT ALL for some reason).

Turning of hardware acceleration in manifest.xml (I'm assuming that's not a desired practice for release app). That works however the whole emulator gets really laggy.

Compressing image to smaller sizes. Still getting "trying to draw too large of a bitmap" error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Move your image in the (hi-res) `drawable` to `drawable-xxhdpi`. But in app development, you do not need to use large image. It will increase your APK file size.

Comment: Ok, so I've deleted the previous reply, because you were right, problem was I needed to clean, delete obj and bin folders and rebuild the solution. Now the problem is scaling, haha.